# Costly process re-seeding production bad data with Laravel in large MySQL dataset

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, data-integrity, database-theory, laravel-seeding

I'm looking for a **saner way** to correct errors in a large seeded database. Solutions are welcome, the saner they are (feel free to question the tools for the job i.e. relational database). I can't afford to truncate the data and reseed all values. Especially when data integrity comes into play. This needs to be robust enough for developer error without having to do entire re-seeds to account for error. Migrations/MySQL/relational DBs don't seem to be flexible enough for my seeded dataset. That's where my knowledge is missing.

Scenario:

- Laravel project, using seeds (JSON) in migration classes, see: [Laravel :
  Migrations & Seeding for production data][1]

  [1]:
  [Laravel : Migrations & Seeding for production data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580088/laravel-migrations-seeding-for-production-data)

  - MySQL database 10k JSON objects representing football players containing 10 values e.g. name, weight, height, team, DOB. Objects iterated through, then inserted into DB with an AI id.

Problem:
MySQL 'height' column was originally, by developer error, of type int and not float, so all heights were rounded to 2m.

Via a migration, I have changed the type to float, and now all height values need to be altered via a reseed, since they're still all 2m (and not, say, 1.76). We need to think about time and cost, having to re-seed thousands of JSON objects into MySQL to alter values on a column whilst maintaining data integrity, since the objects from JSON are assigned their unique Ids on MySQL insert.

To clarify: there are ID-less JSON objects which I seed from. There are several JSON files for the respective football leagues, so I seed these in a modular fashion i.e. when I insert new players. If I need to go in and make a change, there's **no integrity** between the objects in the JSON and those in the database. I have thought about working with the values I have to create a *compound key,*(?) but it still feels like the data is so fragile and prone to *developer error*, and I need a way of sanely managing this, which I don't feel Laravel migrations/seeds offer, especially since you are restricted by only running migrations based on their timestamp values (you cannot specify to rollback a certain migration file that you ran earlier). Perhaps a "source control" for databases is a good idea, if such exists. Note the post is tagged *database-theory* and *data-integrity*, I know that I can just reseed but this can take a few hours of my working day.

Cheers.

Comment: So just run a script and update each row with the new data? 10,000 rows is not much data...?

Comment: My data grows about 10k rows per day. It takes long enough as it is to seed them.

Comment: But you only need to fix the original records - not the new ones - so it doesnt matter if the records keep growing - they should all be ok

Comment: Your proposed solutions are sound for a less complex problem. Let me emphasise "Objects iterated through, then inserted into DB with an AI id." because the JSON objects don't have an ID (they have: name, age, height, weight, dob), they're assigned an ID by MySQL. The objects were seeded in a modular fashion - separate files (they're populated via a Python web scraper). This means I need a way of ensuring the "height" value matches up. This is why the post tag is data-integrity and database-theory respectively. If I add x-thousand players to the wrong team. No way to track, revert..

Comment: I agree with @TheShiftExchange, your problem seems more of updating than seeding. Still, if you feel limitations of a relational database you can consider other database type like -example- object-oriented. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database