# Laravel migration foreign key depending on seed data

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, database-migration, seeding

I need to update an existing Laravel application by migrating and seeding the database.

I have a table like the following:

**items**

- id
- name

And I want to edit the database to look like:

**items**

- id
- name
- type_id (new column)

**types** (new table)

- id
- name

With **type_id** being a not-null foreign key to the **types** table.

The **types** table will be seeded with a Laravel seeder in a following operation. This seeder will be called after each application update and truncate/reinsert some "static" data that only change with updates of the application. It is configured in a way like [Laravel : Migrations & Seeding for production data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580088/laravel-migrations-seeding-for-production-data) for the local/production differences

Everything runs fine when starting from scratch on local database. But on the production database, there are already many records. As it is a not-null key, the migration fails when pushing to this database (actually, a copy of that database for testing)

As a migrating solution, I'd like to add the first **type** record to every existing **item**, but I cannot set the foreign key during the migration, as the **items** table is empty at this stage, and I cannot leave it empty until the seeding, as the migration don't pass.

There are some things I think to:

- Disable the foreign key checks on the database during the whole update, but I'd prefer a solution that allows me to simply push my repository to the server and start my automated deployment script (which essentially call artisan migrate followed by artisan db:seed).
- Call the seeder from the migration just after the creation of the **types** table, but I'm not sure that is a good practice

What should I do ?

Edit: Here's my working migration code using @lukasgeiter answer:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

    Schema::table('items', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->index()->after('name');
    });

    DB::update('update items set type_id = 1');

    Schema::table('items', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');

        // Here I do other stuff to this table
    });

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just disable foreign key checks inside the migration by using `DB::statement` and SQL.

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
// add column
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```

Comment: But when do I run my Seeder ? If I reenable the foreign keys after adding the column without doing anything else it will fail (null still not permitted)

Comment: I thought you'd seed `type_id` with a valid value?

Comment: Yes it's right I will set the right foreign keys but the types table is still empty at this time, it will only be seeded at the next step of the deployment (artisan db:seed)

Comment: I still think this should work though. First you turn key checks off, create the column and turn them on again. Then (when seeding) you seed the `types` table and afterwards update the `type_id` in `items`. Am I wrong?

Comment: No it was me who was wrong =| . I thought dealing with the database that way would cause an error but it actually works as expected. I'll add my working code in the question. Thanks !