# Keep code, database structure and database data in sync between revisions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

This issue has been bothering me for a while and it seems to be a tough question to Google.

I am looking for the best (or at least a decent) way to keep my code, my database structure and the database data in sync with eachother. I am currently using Laravel 5 which provides me with migrations and seeds. The first is excellent for database structure changes. The latter seems ok, but does not take time in consideration.

So I have this laravel installation which I set up a few months ago. It has 20ish tables and a few seeder files.
Now I renamed a column in the existing table structure.

When I start my Laravel site from scratch, I obviously run the migrations first or there will be no tables at all. After that I run my seeds and fail on the insert query for the changed column.

The question arises: shouldn't seeders be time-dependent of migrations? Or should change ALL seeds when a database structure change is made? There must be a better way, am i missing something? How should this be done?

Comment: Some manual work has to be done when changing column names in your tables/migrations, I don't see a problem here. Make the changes to your migrations and all relevant other parts (not only seeders, but also your models/factories ... need to reflect the changes), making sure everything works, push that to your VCS and done.

Comment: Typical how the ''Related' question are a lot better than my own search results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580088/laravel-migrations-seeding-for-production-data?rq=1 anwser my question I think: don't use seeds but for test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with seeds is they need to be updated to reflect the current schema, not whatever historical schema they related to when they were produced.

This is why it's generally best to keep your seeds absolutely minimal. If that's unavoidable to have a clean seed database you can furnish to anyone who needs to work on the project. The risk with a seed database is it can contain modifications that aren't in the migrations, such as when you delete a migration or apply a migration you never commit to the code.

Ideally your project should work from scratch by running migrations and building from seeds, a process you should test intermittently to be sure you didn't break anything.

Comment: Thanks. It's not what I had in mind for seeds. I will use migrations for seeding from now on.

Comment: Sometimes putting "seed" data into the migrations works, but be careful to keep your migration files low-level and never depend on any particular model existing. As you evolve your app models will be created and destroyed, so any migration that depends on a model existing will be problematic.